# Should action buttons within an entry page be identical or different?

Tags: forms, buttons, consistency, data-entry

I am designing an entry screen and there's a few action buttons at the bottom of the page. Should they be identical for consistency or different since they trigger different actions?

[image]

**Behaviour:**

This is the form design for 'New Student'.

1. When the user completed all the fields, user can click 'Save'. This will add the new student into the system. The tab will remain open with all the filled details. User can manually exit the tab by the 'X' button when they are done. But most users prefer to have the tab open after save to review back the details or execute tasks available in the 'Options' button.
2. OR User can tick the 'Create Another' checkbox and then click 'Save'. This will add the new student into the system then empty the form for new submission.

Question:
A new requirement (this is fixed) is added which is to add a 'Save and Close' button so when the user click 'Save', it will add the new student into the system and automatically closes the tab. I have visualise this below

Option 1:

[image]

This is my top choice. The difference between 'Save' and 'Save and Close' is clear. However, if user tick the 'Create Another' checkbox, it will disable the 'Save and Close' button.

**Others**

Option 2:

[image]

Since most user will prefer 'Save' over 'Save and Close', the 'Save and Close' is hidden inside the dropdown. However, I find it impractical to only display one option as hidden. If the user select the 'Save and Close' it will untick the 'Create Another' checkbox if it is previously tick.

Option 3:

[image]

Im not sure about this option since the 'Save' and 'Save and Close' button is identical, it might causes the user to scan both button to feel sure about the differences.

What are your thoughts? Or is there other better way to deliver this.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Note: The better suggestion is below EDIT, but only if it is technically possible.</sub>

Since the extra button makes things overly complicated just omit it. You can add the "Close tab" option next to the "Create another" option:

[image]

Or add the options in a dropdown if this takes too much space.

In my opinion doing this only makes sense if closing the tab is the most wanted option and should then be selected by default. Why is the extra close button a requirement if it isn't what users mostly do? The only win in my suggestion, besides getting the complicated button out of the way, is that a user can see at once what all possible options are after saving.

EDIT:
Since closing the tab after the save by default is the requirement (I hope for a good reason), you should follow that up. There is another option to make this less complicated and that is that the current tab always closes even when "Create another" is selected. But that requires that it is possible to open a new tab for creating another student. Add an option to leave the current tab open and you have given the possibility that users mostly want (select it by default or not). These options are checkboxes (not radio buttons as in the idea above) so it is possible to open a new tab to create another student while leaving the current open.

[image]

Comment: This is an interesting approach @jazZRo since 'Close Tab' and 'Create Another' are additional behaviors on top of 'Save' and stay at the page. The director actually requested that the tab auto-close after 'Save'. The best I could do at my level is to make sure users still have the option to stay on the page after saving since it's the main priority.

Comment: @intnnn So you will want to select "Close tab" by default. Or if it is possible to open a new tab when the current closes, see under EDIT in the answer.

Comment: Now the "create another" option is not saving one click. selecting save another -> Save is probably as much hassle as "Save -> New Student". At this point I'd rather only have the "Save" (and close) button for simplicity.

Comment: @Rad80 I totally agree. This probably is a X-Y problem but it looks like the OP is seemingly not in the position to change the request.